# How to turn on ale linter for specific files

Tags: plugin-ale, eslint

I have the ale linter installed. it works fine for my php files but for some reason when I started doing typescript, it keeps on giving me these error

[image]

with the error message

```
indent: space indentation expected
```

I tried all the options listed in the ale [docs](https://github.com/w0rp/ale#faq-disable-linters), but the only thing that seems to work is when i just shut it off entirely by putting this in my vimrc:

```
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 1
```

How can I do one of the following two:

1) turn it on just for php 
(I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
let g:ale_linters = {
\   'php': ['eslint'],
\}
```

2) make it actually work for typescript without all these errors (it seems all the files are full of errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) didn't work because eslint is a typescript linter, you should pick a php linter.

2)indent is not a an error, take a look at ale option of your linter, it can be turned off most of the time.

Comment: How do I know what linter works for what language?

Comment: @abbood :help ale

Comment: running that command gives me this: https://imgur.com/muIyTxu, which has nothing to do with ale. As a matter of fact i don't directly have ale installed as a plugin, i'm assuming it got included as an extension of one of my existing plugins. checkout my [vimrc](https://gist.github.com/abbood/3f39ee41464fb1268d11a318896e209a) for reference. What am I missing?

Comment: Why did you assume that?
Uncomment ale plugin, install it and try everything again.